# Aws SageMaker Random Cut Forest Real Time

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, boto3, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-opensearch

I'm trying to understand how Sagemaker works. I have some data in my OpenSearch that I need to identify anomalies.

I understand that I can do the following logic:

- Import my OpenSearch data as CSV or use SDK;
- Use the Random Cut Forest (RCF) algorithm;
- Generate an endpoint in SageMaker;

However, my OpenSearch data is real-time and I want the real-time forecasts to have a (real-time) dashboard in which we can observe anomalous behavior and perhaps generate some kind of alert.

Is it possible that when OpenSearch receives new data, a query is automatically run in SageMaker and the result is displayed on a dashboard like Grafana?